# Can someone help me understand how to use the result from nativescript-barcodescanner

Tags: javascript, android, google-api, nativescript, barcode-scanner

The barcode scanner reads the barcode and displays on console log but how to make it look up for the book on Google Book API. The book details such as Title, Author, and Published year should be displayed on a different page. This is the plugin that I followed: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-barcodescanner

This is my **hardcopy-view-model.js file**

```
var observable_1 = require("data/observable");
var dialogs_1 = require("ui/dialogs");
var view = require("ui/core/view");
var nativescript_barcodescanner = require("nativescript-barcodescanner");
const httpModule = require("http");

var BarCodeModel = (function (_super) {
__extends(BarCodeModel, _super);
function BarCodeModel() {
    _super.call(this);
    this.barcodeScanner = new nativescript_barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner();
}
BarCodeModel.prototype.doCheckHasCameraPermission = function () {
    this.barcodeScanner.hasCameraPermission().then(function (permitted) {
        dialogs_1.alert({
            title: "Has Camera permission?",
            message: permitted ? "YES" : "NO",
            okButtonText: "OK"
        });
    }, function (err) {
        dialogs_1.alert(err);
    });
};
BarCodeModel.prototype.doScanWithTorch = function () {
    this.scan(false, true, true, "landscape");
};
;
BarCodeModel.prototype.doScanLandscape = function () {
    this.scan(false, true, true, "landscape");
};
;

BarCodeModel.prototype.scan = function () {
 this.barcodeScanner.scan({
 cancelLabel: "EXIT. Also, try the volume buttons!", 
 cancelLabelBackgroundColor: "#333333", 
 message: "Tap the bulb button or Use the volume button for turning on 
 light", 
 showFlipCameraButton: false,   
 preferFrontCamera: false,     
 showTorchButton: true,        
 beepOnScan: true,             
 torchOn: false,               
 closeCallback: function () { console.log("Scanner closed"); }, 
 resultDisplayDuration: 500,  
 orientation: "landscape",     
 openSettingsIfPermissionWasPreviouslyDenied: true 
 }).then(

 function(result) {
        console.log("---- scanned " +result.text);
        httpModule.request({
            url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes? 
 q=isbn:"+result,
            method: "GET"
        }).then((response) => {
            var obj = response.content.toJSON();
            console.log("Book: " +obj);
            console.log(JSON.parse(response)); 
            alert({
                title:"Scan Result",
                message: "Barcode Format: " + result.format + "\nCode: " + 
 result.text + "\nBook Title: " + result.response,
                okButtonText:"OK"
            });
        });  
     },          
  function(error) {
    console.log("No scan: " + error);
 });
};
;
return BarCodeModel;
}(observable_1.Observable));
exports.BarCodeModel = BarCodeModel;
```

Comment: Docs: [HOW DO I SEARCH](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#PerformingSearch)

Comment: @RandyCasburn, Is this how its supposed to be : httpModule.request({ url: "googleapis.com/books/v1/…; method: "GET"..... Is my httpRequest code correct?

Comment: so what do you get back from Google Books? Here is an example of a valid search that works just fine: https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9781620331538 - this makes me think the contents of 'result` is not a valid ISBN.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, the content of result is 9781416900955, which i scanned of a book. But the output only shows this in the console JS: Scanner closed
JS: ---- scanned 9781416900955

Comment: I want it to display the Title, Author, Published Date, and pageCount on an alert.

Comment: I misunderstood. I thought this: **_but how to make it look up for the book on Google Book API._** was the question. But it seems like you've done this successfully all along. So what **really** is the question then?

Comment: @RandyCasburn, the question is that the code only displays until console.log("---- scanned " +result.text); it does not even read the httpsModule. How to fix this?

Comment: Please edit your question. You question is not **_but how to make it look up for the book on Google Book API._** - your question is **_Can someone help me understand how to use the result from nativescript-barcodescanner_**

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you need to be passing result.text in the URL.  result.text has the actual barcode.

url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:"+result.text,